# Is it possible to install an application in 2 different folders of the same server using MSIEXEC

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, setup-deployment

I am using MSIEXEC in batch file to reconfigure my c sharp console application.
As per our design we need to use same server for both Test and UAT using 2 different folders. 
When I deploy using my version control software ,I use batch file with the MSIEXEC command as follow:

```
msiexec /i <msipath>\Setup.msi TARGETDIR=c:\TestApps\MyApp\App\   /Lime <log path>\logfile.txt /qn
```

In Test region the auto install bat command works fine and  installs exe and dll in c:\TestApps\MyApp\App.
In UAT region though I have mentioned target dir as "c:\UATApps\App" ,It is not installing in the UATApps folder and not even thorowing error.

Any idea To install the application in 2 diff target folders? 
May be possible with the  2 diff setup project .But looking for other options If any .

Comment: Yes, you can. You have to install [multiple instances](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369523(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Looks like transforms need to be added.But not getting the exact flow of using MST files.

Comment: Some how found a temp solution.For a single project ,I am going to keep 2 setup projects and to target 2 diff folders.Not sure If this is the right approach,but so far it works fine.